# Assign static IP address to a new aws instance using terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I already have static IP address but i am trying to assign this IP address to newly create instance by using terraform but unfortunately i am getting new Ip address. Can somebody help?

```
data "aws_eip" "my_instance_eip" {

  public_ip ="3.17.21.34"

}


resource "aws_instance" "Webserver_Instance" {

        instance_type = var.type_webserver

        ami = var.ami_webserver

        key_name = var.key_name

        tags = {

            name = "Webserver_Instance"

        }

        security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.Webserver_SG.name}"]

  }

resource "aws_eip_association" "my_eip_association" {

  instance_id   = aws_instance.Webserver_Instance.id

  allocation_id = data.aws_eip.my_instance_eip.id

}
```

Comment: "unfortunately its not happening" - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any error messages?

Comment: Unrelated but you should also note the comment on the `security_groups` parameter on the `aws_instance` resource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#security_groups. Instead you should use `vpc_security_group_ids`. And considering using `terraform fmt` to format your code.

Comment: @Marcin i am getting a new IP address

Comment: Your code is fine. This means that what you are actually doing is different than what you post in your question.